# Algorithm to calculate the sharpness of an edge of an image

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to calculate the sharpness/blurriness of the edge in an image provided i know which coordinates the edge starts and can calculate the RGB, HSV and CMYK color space. I need it as a possible equation.

Comment: Right now i dont know any algorithm to achieve the same. I have tried applying Gaussian convolution matrix filter but i don't know how to implement and extract the edge itself,like it is possible with imagemagick.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know how to perform convolutions, have a look at the [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).

You convolve the image **I** twice, once with the **x** kernel to get **G**<sub>x</sub>

```
     [-1  0 +1]
Gx = [-2  0 +2] * I
     [-1  0 +1]
```

and once with the **y** kernel to get **G**<sub>y</sub>

```
     [+1 +2 +1]
Gy = [ 0  0  0] * I
     [-1 -2 -1]
```

Then, for each "pixel" in **G**<sub>x</sub> and **G**<sub>y</sub>,

```
G(x,y) = sqrt( Gx(x,y)*Gx(x,y) + Gy(x,y)*Gy(x,y) );
```

**G** now gives you the gradient of the image at (x,y). The magnitude of the gradient gives you a measure of the difference between adjacent pixels, or the sharpness of the edge. High magnitudes indicate a sharp edge; magnitudes near zero indicate no edge. You'll have to play around with the values to see which ones give you what you consider a "sharp" edge or a "blurry" edge since these terms are not very mathematically precise.

Comment: @breaker thanks for the explaining it in detail. I do have a doubt, how is sobel filter different to "difference of Gaussians" filter in this case,ie calculating the sharpness?
[link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians

2. would you mind explaining how to do the same for "Difference_of_Gaussians" as i couldnt understand the algorithm from the above wikipedia link.

Comment: The Sobel operator is an approximation of the first derivative; Difference of Gaussians is an approximation of the second derivative. Either one can give you good results, you just have to choose a kernel and a threshold that works (i.e. identifies your edges) for the image you're using.